# OpenRefine - Converting text column with numbers to numeric type

Tags: openrefine

I created an Age column based on the difference between 2 date columns. Initially I was able to create the Age facet without any issues.

But on reopening the project I am unable to create the Age facet. It looks like the Age column has somehow turned into a text column. And I have to keep converting all cells to numeric before being able to facet by Age each time I reopen the project.

Another issue (is this the cause?) with this column is I noticed wrong values in some Age cells and tried to update the value to leave it blank (i.e. age unknown) but having converted all cells in them column to Numeric the operation wasn't allowed. I am not sure if somewhere I left a cell as blank (text) space while making these corrections. If this is the reason for refine to treat the column as text how do I identify those particular cells and then set them to unknown numeric or null values?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Could you open a new issue on Github ? Thanks! https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues

Comment: @EttoreRizza will do